# Paperclip, Rails 2.3.3 and OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, paperclip

I have code

in view

```
<% uberform_for :profile, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :put }, :url => update_avatar_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>

  <p><%= f.submit 'Upload avatar' %></p>
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
  def update_avatar
    current_user.profile.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:avatar])
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end
```

and in model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :nickname
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:thumb => '100x100>'},
    :path => '#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/avatars/:id/:normalized_basename_:style.:extension',
    :url => '/images/avatars/:id/:normalized_basename_:style.:extension'

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes
end
```

And when i'm trying to upload avatar - nothing arrives to db and to the filesystem. In Logs i see

```
Processing UsersController#update_avatar (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-08-26 11:09:04) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"profile"=>{"avatar"=>#<File:/var/folders/zg/zghNxzjrFP02se1nq1fKQ++++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20090826-3425-1akehpx-0>}, "authenticity_token"=>"Frf1ozk01ePIhvsPSX3k1ophgvHHrnBFKhFcF21co+o="}
  User Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 1) LIMIT 1
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/alec-c4
Completed in 18ms (DB: 1) | 302 Found [http://localhost/update_avatar]
```

and application renders picture /avatars/thumb/missing.png

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:avatar]` is not present in the params hash.  You'll need to use `params[:profile][:avatar]`

Comment: ArgumentError in UsersController#update_avatar
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

and in console
>> p= Profile.find 1
......
>> p.avatar =  File.open('/Users/alec/Documents/Personal Data/avatars/11412573.jpg')
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that there are conflict with plugin http://github.com/netguru/paperclip-extended/tree/master. Removing this plugin makes app work fine.